# code tag shows XML markup then disappears in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The below URL shows some XML in a `<code>` tag.  It works fine in say Edge and Firefox but in Chrome, the markeup shows for a second then disappears just leaving the values as you can see below.  Why is this happening in Chrome?

https://basketball.exposureevents.com/api/resources/venues

[image]

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 70, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try hard refresh, it's simple thing that may solve the problem (if the source of it is in the specific site's CSS/JS code) (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Second, try update you'r Chrome to the last version (70.0.3538.67), go to [image: 3 dots button] on the top bar, there you can see if there is a new update (if there is, it will show up at the first line).
You can check you'r Chrome's version in this link: chrome://settings/help or go to [image: 3 dots button] on the top bar > Help > About Google Chrome.

If you'r Chrome is up to date, you may have some plugin/s that removing the xml tags.
Try accessing to this page via Incognito Mode (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

If it's working in the Incognito Mode, back to you'r main Chrome and then click on [image: 3 dots button] on the top bar > More tools > Extensions. Then, disable all of them and try to enable them one-by-one, on each one you'r enabled, go and check again if the problem is still there.

*Note that some plugins may be enabled also for Incognito Mode, so try the last step anyway.

**Update:** As much as I understand, the root issue is that your code was wrapped with html `<pre>` tag, that makes the browser to treat the XML as HTML tags, that are invisible when rendered in browser.

Comment: It was this gInfinity plugin.  Thanks!